# After jre 1.7.0._u11 update netbeans doesn't work anymore

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, java-7

There's something wrong that I couldn't detect. After jre 1.7.0._u11 update, netbeans doesn't work anymore.

A simple Test.java like this throws an error:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Go Forrest!");
    }
}
```

[image: See the error:]

I've changed the jdk to 1.7.0_u11 too, and set manually **netbeans_jdkhome** variable in the file netbeans.conf, but the problem remains.

I'm using netbeans 7.2.1. on Mac and have uninstalled and installed it again.

Has anyone faced this same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding (SHIFT + F11)? Is the JDK 7u11 properly setup in your project properties (right click on project > Properties > Libraries > Java Platform)?

Comment: I did as you advised, the problem remains. But it is strange, I've refactored the class and changed its name, and it worked. Strange... but is inadmissible, have to refactor every class in a Project. Thanks assylias!

Comment: And yes, the jdk1.7.0_11.jdk is properly set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting my computer, it returned to work normally.